# How to configure postgres+pgbouncer to allow large number of connections

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgbouncer

I am in the process of stress testing pgbouncer with 5000 connections.
The purpose of the test is to multiplex the connection using pgbouncer i.e. 5000 client connection to 500 db connections.

However, I am unable to achieve the target of active 500 connection mark.

My setup is pretty straight forward

(client set using pgbench) ----->pgbouncer + psql

|______multiple boxes______||______1 box_________|

pgbouncer and postgres are present in the same box.

pgbouncer = 1 core (expectation)

postgres = 15 cores (expectation)

- **machine configuration**:

  16 cores

  ulimit -n 10000
- **Postgres configuration**:

  max_connections = 500

  shared_buffers = 1GB

  work_mem = 100kB
- **pgbouncer configuration**:

  pool_mode = transaction

  server_lifetime=6000

  server_idle_timeout=2000

  server_connect_timeout=30

  default_pool_size=500

  pool_size=500

  pkt_buf=4096

  server_login_retry=2
- **client configuration**(8 boxes each 8 cores):

  Each client box mimic as a set for clients using pgbench
  For an 8 core box I set 16 threads to fire the queries

  pgbench -h  -p 6541 -c  -j 16 -d -f pgbench_Script.sql -T 360 -U postgres test

  pgbench_Script.sql

  \setrandom delta 0 100000
  insert into t4.emplog values(nextval('t4.employeeSeq'),:delta);

Active queries on postgres:

```
select count(*) from pg_stat_activity where state like 'active';
count
-------
40
```

My expectation is to have close to 500 active connections to the database via the connection pooler.
**Problem**: 
I only see a handfull of connections ~ 40 active connections

**OBSERVATION:**
I see multiple postgres process in 'idle' state although pgbouncer has all the client being serviced. Suggesting that the pgbouncer is unable to perform to the best.
However, I cannot pin point what is the exact bottle neck.

**Potential bottleneck:**

*client request:* pgbench makes each thread a master of a set on connection. how can I mimic a large set of active concurrent connections?

*pgbouncer :* is my configuration of pgbouncer flawed?

*postgres :* is my configuration of postgres unable to handle large connection?

Comment: 500 connections on single postgres instance is too high. It shoud newer go above `%CPU core count% * 2`.

Comment: I understand it is high, but this is more of a stress test setup to identify points of failure. Is there any repercussion having more than %CPU core count% * 2 connections ?

Comment: Please read this article: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections It gives you an estimation and reasoning for optimal tread count.

Comment: As for stress test - with a properly configured connection pool (like `pgbouncer`) you postgres will never have more than optimal number of connections. I do not see a purpose in a stress test for a situations that should never happen.

Comment: @Igor: The reason for the test is to check the transaction per second(tps) I am able to achieve owing to the high load. Incase of direct connection I get around 11k tps whereas with pgbouncer I get around 3k (500 connections). While using pgbouncer I notice most of my connections 'idle' & am trying to resolve this. I dont see this 'idle' behavior when using direct connections.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko what do you mean by %CPU core count% * 2? My server has 12 cores with 32 GB of RAM. What should I set the maximum connections to?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting '-c' as blank or is it a typo in the question? The '-c' sets the number of clients for the pgbench command. Start by something from 100 and slowly move to 1000 for each instance running pgbench.

```
pgbench -h -p 6541 -c 100 -j 16 -d -f pgbench_Script.sql -T 360 -U postgres test
```